# Redirecting on clicking Login with Google button using Passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

Right now, I want that:

- Whne user clicks on **Login with Google** button, gets redirected to the oAuth consent screen.
- In the consent screen, when the user chooses the account, it gets redirected to the route `/auth/google/redirect`(is this the correct route?) which logs in the user. So, then I want to set a cookie which I'm doing in `app.js`. This shows that the user is logged in.

Now, how do I make a request from the `NavBar` component in my react frontend? For now, I have a button. I want to know the process that happens when I click the button; which backend route should I call?

I'm having real trouble. Please suggest me some resources or help me understand it. Thanks.

**routes/auth.js**

```js
const express = require("express")
const passport = require("passport")
const auth = require("./controllers/auth")
const router = express.Router()

// auth with google
router.get("/google", passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["profile"]
}))

// callback route for google to redirect to
router.get("/google/redirect", passport.authenticate("google"), (req, res) => {
    // what to do here?????
})


module.exports = router
```

**config/passport.js**

```js
const passport = require("passport")
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy
const User = require("../models/User")



passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id)
})

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then((user) => {
    done(null, user)
  })
})


passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.clientID,
      clientSecret: process.env.clientSecret,
      callbackURL: "/auth/google/redirect",
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {

      // check if the user exists
      User.findOne({ googleID: profile.id }).then((currentUser) => {
        if (!currentUser) {
          // if the user doesn't exist; create a new user
          new User({
            username: profile.displayName,
            googleID: profile.id,
          })
            .save()
            .then((newUser) => {
              console.log(`New user created- ${newUser}`)
              done(null, newUser)
            })
        }

        if (currentUser) {
          console.log(`The current user is- ${currentUser}`)
          done(null, currentUser)
        }
      })
    }
  )
)
```

**NavBar.js**

```js
import React from "react"

const NavBar = () => {
    return (
        <Link to="/auth/google"> // is this the correct URL???
            <Button>Login with Google</Button> //how to handle onClick here
        </Link>
    )
}

export default NavBar
```

**app.js**

```js
app.use(cookieSession({
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    keys: [process.env.cookieKey]
}))

// intialize passport
app.use(passport.initialize)
app.use(passport.session)
```

Comment: you can have onClickListener in the Button component and make a call to your /auth/google backend route

Comment: @Hari and after that?

Comment: There are plenty of articles which explain step by step how this can be achieved.
For example: https://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-set-up-twitter-oauth-using-passport-js-and-reactjs-9ffa6f49ef0

Comment: Great. Do you have another article with Google oAuth and React? @DhruvShah